# Windows Django data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: sql-server, django, windows, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server studio v17.2

This is the code that works fine in my local computer

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        # 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        # 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'database',
        'HOST': '10...',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        #'DRIVER':'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',}
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> windows django data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Have you installed ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server on the server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yeah i did, and it still the same. I tried to add it in odbc manager but still not working. did i miss some step. please help